# Categories don't show on JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

I'm writing code in a `JPanel`, it's all working fine. However, the categories are not displayed when I view the panel.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
   for(Category c : categories){
        comboModel.addElement(c);
        NoResultsLabel.setVisible(false);
    }

    CategoriesCombo.setModel(comboModel);
```

So that in the customized code inside the design I write the following:

```
CategoriesCombo.setModel(comboModel);
```

However, the categories still don't show in the combobox.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. There is no way we can help based on a couple of lines of code. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a JFrame with a single JComboBox added to the frame. 90% of the time while you create the SSCCE you will find your problem because you are simplifying the problem to only a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to change NoResultsLabel.setVisible(false); to NoResultsLabel.setVisible(true); and let us know if your problem is solved

```
 NoResultsLabel.setVisible(false);  to NoResultsLabel.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your loop is ok,i mean Categories and Category class and
make sure your CategoriesCombo is a JComboBox type and then add your ComboBox to Jpanel
then use DefaulComboBoxModel for give a model to ComboBox
like this :

```
class test extends JFrame{
private JComboBox combo;
private final DefaultComboBoxModel model;
private Jpanel panel;
test()
{
   combo = new JComboBox();
   model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
   panel = new Jpanel();
   createModel();
   combo.SetModel(model);
   panel.add(Combo);
   add(panel);    
 }    
       void createModel()
       {
          for(Category c : categories){
          model.addElement(c);
          NoResultsLabel.setVisible(false);
       }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {  
     test t = new test();
  }
}
```